# User Connection speed test *before* page load?

Tags: jquery, performance, usability, vimeo

I have an idea for a site, but it's bandwidth/processor heavy.

You can see (or not see) it here: [marckremers.com](http://marckremers.com)

Basically, it's 6 webcasts all playing at once, i cant think of a better way to show potential clients a visually enjoyable and dynamic overview then this. Websites aren't static, I want to show my UIs and designs being used! Not showing 'dumb' stills.

But it's processor and bandwidth heavy. I'm wondering if there is a good way to test the users speed first, so if their speed is up to it, I can show them the bells and whistles moving version, if their connection is slow, they get the basic which they can still play if they want.

Doing speed connection tests is kinda old school and not desirable, but I think it's warranted for this kind of presentation angle.

I've googled around but there doesn't seem to be anything out their that's accurate.

Also wondering if there is a different way of doing it, like timing the play buttons to start sequentially?

Answer (score 3):

I would let the users decide. Speed and processor tests are possible, but they take time.

For what it's worth though, I find the six webcasts running in parallel rather annoying. I would use static images, and show the animations on click or something.

Comment: Maybe I should have a gif animation div that on hover dissapears to reveal the vimeo player as static. Apprciate your feedback but i like the noisiness of it (also appeals to the kinda clients i like to get :-)

Comment: @RGBK fair enough. The animated GIF idea sounds good - although they may take up as much bandwidth as the video in the end if they are very detailed. Hmmm